# Holding Tzitzis for Maariv

Tags: tzitzis, shacharis-morning-prayer, shema, maariv

Why do we hold and kiss the tzitzis for "vayomer Hashem" in Kriyas Shema during Shacharis but not during Maariv? I have never seen a siddur that instructs you to do so during Maariv.